# What is gained when you .extend() an obj prototype with itself

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was looking at some code, and just to make sure I wasn't losing my mind with missing the obvious as this looks like to me, there is nothing gained. Seems like a wasteful usage of $.extend() but perhaps someone can shed some light on something I might be missing with inheritance.

So, we have this.

```
_letsCreateNameSpace('US.somenew.obj');
//this is based on S.stoyanov namespace pattern, what this _letsCreateNameSpace does.
```

then I seen this in some code, and it didn't make sense to me.

```
US.somenew.obj = function(){
  // some this var assignments.
  this.blah = $foo;
}

// this usage of extend escapes me. I don't see a need at this point here.
$.extend(US.somenew.obj.prototype, {
  // a bunch of new methods


}
```

I do not see at all the benefit of using $.extend() instead of just the following, as there is no extending anything but itself.

```
 US.somenew.obj.prototype = {
   // a bunch of new methods
 }
```

there is no 'deep' extend or anything.. just looks like a verbose way of extending a prototype for no reason.

Am I missing something? Is there some "forest behind the tree's" methodology I am missing here?

Answer (score 3):

`$.extend` will copies to the `prototype` the methods given **without** overwrite the `prototype` object itself. So for instance, if you have:

```
// inheritance
US.somenew.obj.prototype = myproto;

US.somenew.obj.prototype =  {
   // you lost the inheritance with `myproto`, here
}
```

Using `$.extend` will prevent that. Plus, you won't lose some default property. For example, the `constructor`:

```
US.somenew.obj = function () {};

US.somenew.obj.prototype = {};

var o = new US.somenew.obj();

console.log(o.constructor === US.somenew.obj) // false, in that case is `Object`
```

Where:

```
US.somenew.obj = function () {};

$.extend(US.somenew.obj.prototype, {});

var o = new US.somenew.obj();

console.log(o.constructor === US.somenew.obj) // true
```

Comment: awesome explanation. Now it makes complete sense. I see the need for it. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think the only benefit is to keep the original prototype object intact instead of overwriting it with a new object.
The `constructor` property will refer to the correct function (`US.somenew.obj`) instead of referring to `Object`. Of course you could just reassign `.prototype.constructor` correctly (and this is done quite often), but you can avoid this with extending the existing object.

From a coding style point-of-view it seems to make sense as well: Usually you don't want to *replace* the prototype, you want to *add* properties to it.

Comment: I see - that makes sense and something I thought of, but I figured the  original usage would be for 'new instantiation' of objects but that isn't possible with an explicit namespace declaration. hmmm. ok, I figured the code would be multi-instanced, but that doesn't seem to be the case. ok, thanks for your answer.